# Obfuscating Android Source Files via commandline and produce APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Is there a way to obfuscate source files, then build it and produce an .apk file via the commandline? I have android studio installed

Answer (score 0):

If your project has the default android build variants `debug` and `release`, you can run the following from the command line to build a release apk:

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

By default, the release build variant uses proguard default configuration file `proguard-rules.pro` in your project, which should obfuscate your source files.